# using Navigationlink in actionsheet swiftui

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, actionsheet

Does anyone know how I can go to another view from an actionsheet in Swiftui?

Currently I use this as a button in actionsheet:

```
.actionSheet(isPresented: $actionsheet) {
    ActionSheet(title: Text("Actions"), message: Text("Choose action"), buttons: [
        .default(
            NavigationLink(destination: adddetails()) {
                Text("Add details")
            }
        ),
        .default(Text("New")),
        .default(Text("Delete")),
        .cancel()
    ])                              
}
```

But it won't build. Even though Xcode doesn't give me an error. Does anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control a `NavigationLink` programmatically by using the `isActive` parameter with a binding. Then, in your `ActionSheet`, you can toggle that binding.

The other key is that the `NavigationLink` needs to be embedded in your original view hierarchy and not the `ActionSheet`. You can conditionally display it with an `if` statement so that it's only there if active (and thus invisible unless the navigate button is pressed):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var actionSheetOpen = false
    @State private var navigationLinkActive = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            if navigationLinkActive {
                NavigationLink("", destination: Text("Detail"), isActive: $navigationLinkActive)
            }
            
            Button("Open action sheet") {
                actionSheetOpen.toggle()
            }
            .actionSheet(isPresented: $actionSheetOpen) {
                ActionSheet(title: Text("Actions"), message: Text("Choose action"), buttons: [
                    .default(Text("Navigation"), action: {
                        navigationLinkActive = true
                    }),
                    .default(Text("New")),
                    .default(Text("Delete")),
                    .cancel()
                ])
            }
            
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

Comment: The use of the `if` statement is cool. I would never think it out myself. Most of the posts I found use `EmptyView`. But Apple's doc says that view should be rarely needed. That's why I tried to look for a better approach and stumbled on here. In my opinion, for a common scenario like navigating to another view from action sheet, both approaches are not ideal. Hope Apple will work out a better way in future.

Comment: Unfortunately after actually trying the approach I find it has an issue when animation is enabled. The `NavigationLink` view shows in the original view during the transition. So it seems using `EmptyView` is the right way to go.